# Java: Generics Inheritance

Tags: java, class, generics, inheritance, casting

I have the following interface for a marshaller that marshalls an `Object` to a `DataNode` object and back:

```
public interface DataMarshaller<T> {

    /**
     * returns the actual class that this marshaller is capable of marshalling.
     * @return 
     */
    Class<T> getDataClass();

    /**
     * marshalls the object to a DataNode
     * 
     * @param object
     * @return 
     */
    DataNode marshal(T object);

    /**
     * unmarshalls the object from a DataNode
     * 
     * @param node
     * @return 
     */
    T unMarshal(DataNode node);

}
```

To make sure that I'm able to get the correct marshaller for an object I also have the method `Class<T> getDataClass()` that returns its class (that would have been lost after compiling because of type erasure).

Now I wanted to implement this interface in a class that is able to marshal objects of type `Octree<T>` like this:

```
public class OctreeMarshaller<T> implements DataMarshaller<Octree<T>> {

    @Override
    public Class<Octree<T>> getDataClass() {
        return Octree.class; //<- compiletime error
    }

    @Override
    public DataNode marshal(Octree<T> object) {
        //...
    }

    @Override
    public Octree<T> unMarshal(DataNode node) {
        //...
    }


}
```

My problem is now that (of course) `Octree.class` is not of type `Class<Octree<T>>` but rather of the non generic type `Class<Octree>` and Java won't allow me to cast it to `Class<Octree<T>>`.

The question is now: is there a more elegent way to solve that than the two I already considered:

- change the return value in the interface from `Class<T>` to `Class<?>`
- change the class signature of `OctreeMarshaller` to `public class OctreeMarshaller implements DataMarshaller<Octree>`

Comment: Not sure what you're using the `Class` object for, but maybe super type tokens are what you're looking for: http://gafter.blogspot.sk/2006/12/super-type-tokens.html. They're a way to express "nested" generic types at runtime, although any actual type checks you have to implement yourself. (That is, you don't automatically get a "smarter" `Class.cast()` or anything.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Without an instance of `Octree<T>` you cannot construct a class object of type `Class<Octree<T>>`. But since we know (due to type erasure) there is only one class `Octree` during run time, it's safe to write

```
public class OctreeMarshaller<T> implements DataMarshaller<Octree<T>> {

    @Override
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public Class<Octree<T>> getDataClass() {
        return (Class<Octree<T>>)(Class<?>)Octree.class;
    }

    [...]
}
```

Comment: This solved my problem. I never thought of double casting it - so thanks! :)

Answer (score 1):

With `Class` of a generic type, you need a double cast:

```
public Class<Octree<T>> getDataClass() {
    return (Class<Octree<T>>)(Class<?>)Octree.class;
}
```

Whacky, but it works.

Comment: But casting is a contradiction to type safety